# Trouble with defaultSorted and React Bootstrap table Next

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have created a table with react bootstrap table next and I try to use the defaultSorted features. Here is an example from the doc:

```
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';

const columns = [{
  dataField: 'id',
  text: 'Product ID',
  sort: true
}, {
  dataField: 'name',
  text: 'Product Name',
  sort: true
}, {
  dataField: 'price',
  text: 'Product Price',
  sort: true
}];

const defaultSorted = [{
  dataField: 'name',
  order: 'desc'
}];

<BootstrapTable
  keyField="id"
  data={ products }
  columns={ columns }
  defaultSortDirection="asc"
/>
```

What I don't understand is where to use the defaultSorted constant? Should I add it to one of my column or in the bootstraptable? I have tried different solution and none of them seems to works.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`defaultSorted` is an attribute on BootstrapTable itself. The trick here is to use the same column name for which you have 'sort: true' added.

You can have a look at a sandbox demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/jl94vl66kw).

Answer (score 1):

```
// <BootstrapTable sort={ { columnName, order} } />
```

Example:

```
<BootstrapTable sort={ { dataField: 'firstName', order: 'desc' } } />
```

Make sure to give the exact column name.

Comment: Any idea, if it will work if the field is a date field ?